# -[NSTextView setTag:] does not exist... how can I identify different text views?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

There does not seem to be a `setTag:` for `NSTextView`.
So if I have multiple `NSTextView`s, how can I access them without creating iVars for each one?

I know a possibility could be through the delegate... but I have the same problem there: how to identify which `NSTextView` is messaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own tag property for `NSTextView` in category and make it editable from Xcode Interface Builder

```
IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface NSTextView (Tag)

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic, nullable) IBInspectable NSString *myTag;

@end

const NSMutableDictionary* tagsMap;

@implementation NSTextView (Tag)

- (void) dealloc {
    tagsMap[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self]] = nil;
}

- (void) setMyTag:(NSString *)myTag {
    if (tagsMap == nil) {
        tagsMap = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    tagsMap[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self]] = myTag;
}

- (NSString*) myTag {
    return tagsMap[[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:self]];
}

@end
```

Comment: I guess using "categories" wasn't too hard... thanks... this worked

Answer (score -1):

Just adding an approach... simple... but dirty.

When I instantiate say 2 NSTextViews... I set each one with a different fontSize: (49 and 50) and so I can identify them that way.

```
-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTextView* textView = (NSTextView *)[notification object];
    if ([textView.font isEqualTo:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:49]]) {
        NSLog(@"1");
    } else if ([textView.font isEqualTo:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:50]]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"2");
    }
}
```